# Bootstrap 2.1.1 "Collapsible" not opening first time in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

The first time you click to open the bootstrap "collapsible" accordion in IE 7/8/9, it does not open. Anyone else run into this or can figure out why?

Thanks

---

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pWU4n/7/

```html
<div class="accordion category-list-accordion">
    <div id="category-5" class="accordion-group" style="display: block; ">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse">
                CLICK ME TWICE THE FIRST TIME TO OPEN IN IE
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="category-5-accordion" class="accordion-body collapse">
            <div class="accordion-inner span33">
                "Bootstrap was made to not only look and behave great in the latest desktop browsers (as well as IE7!)"
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#category-5").click(function() {
        $("#category-5-accordion").collapse("toggle");
    });
});
```

`<head>` includes :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This problem is not related to IE : this will happen on any browser that doesn't support **transitions** (or if it is deactivated).

That's because **you need to initialize the plugin first**. If you don't, it both initializes and toggles the collapse on the first click : the default initialization toggles the collapse ([doc](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse)), and without the transitions, the collapse is toggled twice in a row without being seen.

Here is what you should do :

```js
$("#category-5-accordion").collapse({toggle: false});
$("#category-5").click(function() {
    $("#category-5-accordion").collapse("toggle");
});
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/pWU4n/8/)